# Going into directory using bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have the following functions in my ~/.bash_aliases file

```
mycd() {
  dir=$(cat)
  echo "$dir"
  cd "$dir"
}
alias c=mycd
```

and

```
gotoD() {
  find -name $1 -type $2 | awk '{ print $0 }' | sort -k2 | head -1 | c
}
alias goto=gotoD
```

I want to be able to type

```
goto directory_name d
```

and have the functions search for the directory and cd into the nearest one
The problem is that though the found path to the directory gets into mycd, it is unable to actually change directories and simple remains in the same directory without any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you wrote `without any errors`, show us these errors !

Comment: I mean that when i run the command (goto directory_name d) nothing happens, no error messages, the prompt just moves to a new line staying at the same directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you put a command into a pipeline, you force that command to be executed as a separate process.  Since each process has it's own current directory, you only end up changing that one process's current directory and not the current directory of the shell you were typing in.  Try implementing gotoD like this:

```
gotoD() {
  cd $(find -name $1 -type $2 | awk '{ print $0 }' | sort -k2 | head -1)
}
```

Now the logic of finding the proper directory is still executed in another process, but `cd` command is  executed by the main process.

Answer (score 0):

### Set Proper Bash Option: cdable_vars

You're probably looking for the correct *shopt* option to set `cdable_vars`. The [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) says:

> cdable_vars
>
> If this is set, an argument to the cd builtin command that is not a directory is assumed to be the name of a variable whose value is the directory to change to.

This simplifies your solution. For example:

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
goto=/etc
cd goto
```

Instead of assigning a static directory to goto, though, you could use a script, function, or pipeline to assign a directory name to *goto*.